# DBS API Server Error 500 on Sandbox calls

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, request, banking

I was just experimenting with the DBS API Sandbox here (https://www.dbs.com/developers/). We have to use OAuth2 to get the access token before passing it in the header to authenticate API calls. When I tested everything out on their test client UI I got the results back from the API call.

However, when I coded my simple node app, I could successfully perform OAuth2 and get an access token, but when passed in together with the clientId, got a server error 500 from the API.

For example, the `GET` call to get a bank account details:

```
const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: dbsHost + rootPath + '/accounts/22909292550739201999095',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'accessToken': accessToken,
        'clientId': clientId
    }
}
request(options, (error, response, body) => {
    // Server error 500
    console.log(response)
})
```

These were the exact instructions as those given on the test client UI. On closer inspection I realised the access token I always got back had 488 characters, but that of the test client UI only had 475. Any reason for this difference? How do I know OAuth2 was performed correctly and I'm getting the right access token?

Here's how I did OAuth2:

On the frontend:

```
let authorizationUri = dbsHost + rootPath + '/oauth/authorize'
authorizationUri += '?client_id=' + clientId
authorizationUri += '&redirect_uri=' + redirectUri
authorizationUri += '&scope=Read'
authorizationUri += '&response_type=code'
authorizationUri += '&state=0399'
windows.location.assign(authorizationUri)
```

And at the `redirect_uri` endpoint once I get back the authorization code:

```
app.get('/authCallback', (req, res) => {
    let authCode = req.query.code
    // Encode client_id:client_secret in base-64 to pass in as Auth Basic Header
    let b64 = new Buffer(clientId + ':' + clientSecret).toString('base64')
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: dbsHost + rootPath + '/oauth/tokens',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + b64
        },
        form: {
            'code': authCode,
            'redirect_uri': redirectUri,
            'grant_type': 'token',
            'state': '0399'
        }
    }
    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Access Token Error', error.message)
            return res.status(500).json('Authentication failed');
        }
        let json = JSON.parse(body)
        let accessToken = json['access_token']
        // Make a call with this access token
    })
})
```

Comment: I hope the problem is resolved by now? I have also experience problems when I use DBS API, I follow exactly the "TRY IT" method to get my access token but cannot use that token to call the API. did you use their demo id and pw (iw036/123456) to get authorisation code? Not sure if that's valid to use to get the "correct" authorisation code and access token... @leonardloo